# HtmlAgilityPack cannot extract child nodes in footer element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape data from web site with HtmlAgilityPack. One site has this structure:

```
<footer id="footer-index"><div class="container-fluid bg-dark-blue">
<div class="container bg-dark-blue text-white">

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
        <p>
        <strong>XXXX</strong>
        <br>viale XXXXXXX
        <br>12345 XXXXXX
        <br>CF/P.IVA XXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </p>
        <p>Tel <a class="text-white" href="tel:+3912345">+39 123456</a></p>
        <p class="text-white">Fax +39 123456</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 d-print-none">
        <p><a href="/it/cookies.html" class="text-white">Informativa su Privacy e Cookie</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">    
        <p>Copyright 2018 XXXXX<br>Tutti i diritti riservati.</p>                    
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

</div>    
</footer>
```

I can capture footer element with

```
pageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//footer");
```

but the content of the footer is not captured. There is a way to get the footer content without constraint to know the structure of the footer' content?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by "the content is not captured"? What do you try to do with the selected node after that

Comment: I apologize for my question not clear... I need to read the text whitin the node footer but the property InnerHtml is empty.

Comment: I wonder why the content of InnerHtml property is empty.

Comment: Your code works for me but html from question is not valid. There is extra closing `div` tag.

Comment: In fact I noticed that the html piece contains a formatting error but it is only an excerpt from the page. Unfortunately I understood why the footer node is empty ... It is loaded dynamically with a javascript ... So at the time of executing the LoadHtml method the footer is not loaded. Is there any solution? Thank you

Comment: You can use tools called [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) or usual browser plus selenuim webdriver.